# RecyclerViewの要素を取得したい

Tags: android

ListViewであれば､

```
ListView listView = (ListView)parent;
String value = (String)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

みたいな感じでタッチした行の中身を取り出せますが､これをRecyclerViewで実装するにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか?

よろしくおねがいします｡

Answer (score 0, accepted):

代替策として、adapterにリスナを独自実装して、View定義時に無名関数としてリスナにそのポジションのデータを渡すことで実装しました。

Answer (score 1):

```
RecycerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview);
YourViewHolder viewHolder = (YourViewHolder)recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
```

これで取れます。キャストに失敗する可能性があるので気をつけて下さい。心配な場合は`instanceOf`で確認してます。